# File filled with '\x00' and '\x0013' strings

Tags: python, scp

I read a file in colab, line by line. I split each line using ',' and then convert each element to float. In colab all works.

I transfer this file on a remote machine using `scp` and performing the same operation on this remote machine, when I convert each element to float, I receive an error saying that the element cannot be converted and this because, printing the element, it's full of "\x00" or "\x0013".

When I copied the file, I received a `Disk quota exceeded`.

Does `scp` put this symbols if the copied file is partial?

Comment: Tons of `\x00` in a text file often happens when the file is UTF16 encoded and then read as Latin1 of UTF-8. You should show what the first line looks like in both system to make sure and allow us to propose a way to parse it correctly.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I updated my answer saying that I received a `Disk quota exceeded` while transfer. Could be this the cause?

Comment: IMHO these are 2 distinct problems. One is the encoding problem. The exceeded quota error is likely to be unrelated (excepted that the file may be big)